# A script that uses placeholder attribute to show a typing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

An easy to use type feature that uses the placeholder attribute and setTimer to give the effect of a user typing. Helpful if you need to draw attention to the search box field.

I'm looking to know if this type of implementation would be a performance impact or cause browser lag. Help in making this more condensed would also be helpful. I was thinking about using $.extend, but leaned away. Any reason why I shouldn't make this a jquery plugin?

https://jsfiddle.net/googabeast/jsepy3ed/

```
obj = {
    searchTxt: [
        "Welcome. What are you searching for? ",
        "Something else to type out "
        "Note the space at the end -> "
    ],
    hasFocus:false
}

if(obj.searchTxt !== null && obj.searchTxt !== "undefined"){
    var i = 0, ct = 0; obj.typeIt;

    function type(){
        obj.typeIt = obj.searchTxt[ct].slice(0, ++i);
        if(obj.typeIt === obj.searchTxt[ct]){
            i = 0;
            if(ct === obj.searchTxt.length-1){
                ct = 0;
            }else{
                ++ct;
            }
            return;
        };
        $(".searchBox").attr("placeholder", obj.typeIt);
        setTimeout(type, 80);
    };
    type();


    $(window).on({
        focus: function(){ obj.hasFocus = true; },
        blur: function(){ obj.hasFocus = false; }
    }).trigger("focus");

    setInterval(function(){
        if(obj.hasFocus){
            type();
        };
    }, 10000);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Performance Considerations**

As the code stands now, every time the `type` function is invoked (that is, every 80 milliseconds) the code will parse the DOM looking for any elements with the `searchBox` class.

You can improve the code's efficiency by moving that expensive operation outside the function.

```
var i = 0, ct = 0, searchBox = $(".searchBox"); obj.typeIt;

function type(){
    // ...
    searchBox.attr("placeholder", obj.typeIt);
    // ...
};
```

If you know there'll only be one element with the `searchBox` class, you could improve its efficiency a step further by using the native `document.querySelector` method.

```
var i = 0, ct = 0, searchBox = document.querySelector(".searchBox"); obj.typeIt;

function type(){
    // ...
    searchBox.setAttribute("placeholder", obj.typeIt);
    // ...
};
```

**Timeout/Interval Overlap**

This one's not a biggie, but it's good to be aware of when working with `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

Your interval function is running every 10 seconds to invoke `type`, while within the `type` function a timeout is running every 80 milliseconds to invoke `type` again (until the end of the search text short circuits that behavior).

If the code happens to be in the middle of writing out some search text when the 10-interval kicks in, you'll see some unusual behavior: multiple characters will be written within 80 milliseconds.

For something like this, that's probably not a major issue (you'll only see it happen when the search text is abnormally long or the interval time is abnormally short), but if you want to account for it, you can eliminate `setInterval` altogether. Instead, you can put a 10-second timeout in the "dead end" branch of the `type` function (the `if` block that short-circuits the 80-ms timeout upon reaching the end of the search text), just before the `return` statement.

```
function type(){
    obj.typeIt = obj.searchTxt[ct].slice(0, ++i);
    if(obj.typeIt === obj.searchTxt[ct]){
        i = 0;
        if(ct === obj.searchTxt.length-1){
            ct = 0;
        }else{
            ++ct;
            /* This replaces the setInterval call later in your code: */
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(obj.hasFocus){
                    type();
                }
            },10000);
        }
        return;
    };
    $(".searchBox").attr("placeholder", obj.typeIt);
    setTimeout(type, 80);
};
```

This ensures that `type` is invoked every 80 milliseconds while typing out the search text, and then every 10-seconds between search texts.

Another option is to use the `clearTimeout` method to make sure you don't have duplicate timeouts for the same function call running in parallel.

```
// define a timeout variable
var i = 0, ct = 0, timeout; obj.typeIt;

function type(){
    // ...
     if(timeout){clearTimeout(timeout);} // eliminate duplicate timeouts
     timeout = setTimeout(type, 80);
}
```

This is useful if there are multiple entry points for the `type` function, such as if you were to invoke it from the window's `onFocus` event.

Comment: Thanks for the review!

I attempted your suggestions and was able to devise this working solution. https://jsfiddle.net/googabeast/jsepy3ed/1/

Onlything is now when you leave window focus and come back it is re-running the function. Without the typeit() function in the window.focus the typeit() function will never run again when window does have focus https://jsfiddle.net/googabeast/jsepy3ed/2/

Lastly tried to make typeIt a self executing function and that just causes it to run once as well. https://jsfiddle.net/googabeast/jsepy3ed/3/

Comment: See my updated review. The `clearTimeout` function can be used to prevent duplicate timeouts from being queued up simultaneously, so you could safely slip the `type()` invocation in your onFocus event again.

Comment: Ahhh... completely skipped over that idea. Thanks!